# Need help, accessing more levels of a json/twitter search

Tags: json, twitter, playframework-2.1, loops

I'm using example from @diegolparra of doing a twitter search and/or a streaming.

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{WebSocket, Action, Controller}
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Iteratee, Concurrent, Enumerator}
import play.api.libs.oauth.{OAuthCalculator, RequestToken, ConsumerKey}

case class Tweet(from: String, text: String)

object Tweets extends Controller {
  implicit val tweetReads = (
    (__ \ "from_user_name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "text").read[String]
    )(Tweet)

  def tweetList(query: String) = Action {
    Async {
      val results = 50
      val responsePromise =
        WS.url("http://search.twitter.com/search.json")
          .withQueryString("q" -> query, "rpp" -> results.toString).get

      responsePromise.map {
        response =>
          val tweets = Json.parse(response.body).\("results").as[Seq[Tweet]]
          Ok(views.html.tweetlist(tweets))
      }
    }
  }

  val consumerKey =         ConsumerKey("EBcP4MM9VnI64L8RZLO7g","SVi7XyyNpWzidR2Zx2HVNZ7kZTwFGxpqGKqhOeA")

  val accessToken = RequestToken("1228081488-sLSztNAm0ST2kssCkBNRyhSsmk8SP5dtcbX1ZE2", "GxHUymXdyTYRZxw4bbTbgN8Xh53jKxC1KwvgsVwUU")

  def stream(keywords: String) = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
    val out: Enumerator[String] = Concurrent.unicast[String](onStart = pushee => {
      def twitterIteratee = Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]]{ ba =>
        val msg = new String(ba, "UTF-8")
        pushee.push(msg)
        println(msg)
      }
      WS.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=" + keywords)
        .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, accessToken))
        .get(headers=> twitterIteratee)
    })

    val in = Iteratee.ignore[String]
    (in, out)
  }
}
```

This example get from result of twitter search the fields, from_user_name and text. Now i need to access created_at date and one more level (node user) to get from user: profile_image_url and lang.

Please, any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At Devoxx France, Guillaume Bort showed an example of tweets-fetching getting some "deep" informations. You can find the code here: https://github.com/adericbourg/devoxxfr2013/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala

It does not show the properties you need but using that sample and the Twitter API documentation, you may manage to get what you need.

Hope this helps, so.